# how to zoom in/out using android phone camera

Tags: android

i am using the camera.setSmoothZoom(i) function of the Camera class but its not helping me out. i have tried out camera.getParameters().setZoom(i) function but still i am not getting any success. Does anyone know how to zoom in/zoom out on android phone camera..
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setZoom() function wasn't added until API Level 8 (aka Froyo, Android 2.2). Right now, you probably don't have access to a device running Froyo.

You'll need to manually set the camera parameters. See the zxing Barcode Scanner app for an example of how to do this:

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraConfigurationManager.java

(Search that file for `setZoom`.)

Also, keep in mind that not all cameras support zoom. You'll need to check, either by calling isZoomSupported (API Level 8) or checking the parameters string for `zoom-supported`.